# jQquery Mobile site project for categorised notes - sanity check please?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, html, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I am asking for your advice and a sanity check, please. For a couple of years I have thought about building a **mobile site** for my own purposes  (initially) that will allow me consistent interface on the web and on a mobile phone. My initial target is Android 4 and above.

1. The central idea is to make **notes** via web interface. It is easy to
   edit on a full PC. Basic formatting is necessary - bold, italic,
   lists. I should have some basic editing / adding capability from the phone.
2. Possibly I might need to add images. This at a later stage.
3. I will need to use tables.
4. View these categorised notes on my phone when I need to access that information quickly.
5. Information should be searchable.
6. I should be able to categorise that information both hierarchically and by labels.
7. On the phone the last copy of the information should be available even when there is no internet access. That is the key bit of this project - clear, well structured information, easily available when needed.

So far I have done some 7 websites 6 - 9 years ago and this year I did a responsive design interface with **jQuery** and **HTML5**. I have access to **Apache** on a linux hosting site. I have looked into **jQuery Mobile**. I think jQuery mobile should be great for my front-end. From my past work with LAMP servers I think I have to have a database backend to this project. What I have looked into so far suggests that the best would be to invest some time in learning **Ruby on Rails** (which looks very interesting to me) and use that as a back end interface with a database. What database I should use, I don't know. I have in the past used mySQL, also programmed Access and a bit DB2. I have heard a lot of good stuff about postgres. However considering the mobile phone, I think I should go with **SQLite** probably? What should be the general mechanism for updating the phone from the net?

How does the above look?

Maybe there are some projects which already do something like this?

I don't think I should use some big CMS systems with their bloat and all, because I really want this thing to work for me. Same goes for generic note taking systems such as Evernote. So I am wanting to build it from the ground up, unless there is some similar lightweight project that I could build upon. I am not in a particular hurry, but I am about to get started soon.

A great type of answer for me would be one which tells what major components I should use for this project. It also would be good to know if I am overlooking some important bits.

I appreciate that what I am asking is a large question, but I am not expecting a Wikipedia in response. A **sanity check** and **pointers** in the right direction is what I need.

Thank you for your time and thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a wall of text... 1.-7. are all achievable by using jquery mobile and HTML5  and a good database architecture as backend. I don't see any BIG problems in your idea. What database you use is up to you, your requirements are not that special, that it would require some specialized product. Any established database backend should do the job.

For updating the content on your phone take a look on [HTML Offline Cache](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) and implement an update feature in your Frontend.

Comment: I am sorry for the wall of text :) I wanted to avoid asking a *very* general question. Thanks alot for your answer, and the pointer to diveintohtml5 is absolutely excellent. If I understood you correctly - update would would be like a page reload button (like one with 2 circular arrows) and what it would then pull the newest version from the  site. How one would go about updating in the reverse direction if an edit or addition is made on the mobile? That probably should be done through the same form on the website. But how about syncing changes made when internet was not available?

Comment: refreshing could be done manually with an refresh button or simply automatically with pageevents in jqm. HTML5 offline cache supports also offline storage for variables for a longer time, i think you could start with that. synching different offline and online content requires some thoughts about merging strategies for your app, but this would go too far in this context. Don't think too much in detail or you will never start your project ;)

Comment: Take a look @ this simple example: http://web.archive.org/web/20131211013807/http://www.sitepoint.com/offline-web-application-tutorial/